# How to set reference to a c# file using an exposed field from a scriptable object?

Tags: unity, c#

Can't wrap my head around this, In my game I have the following:

SpecificItem.CS - different items that have different programmed functions/methods into them.
SpecificItemDataContainer.CS - scriptable objects for every different specificItem stats.

I have around 50 to hundreds of SpecificItem along with their respective containers. And I would like to be able to get reference to the different SpecificItems script at runtime by adding them to their corresponding SpecificItemDataContainers.

Turns out I can't drag/reference objects C# files from the project window to a scriptable objects serialized field.

I've thought of just adding each and every into an every SpecificItem scripts into a empty game object and creating a prefab to reference the script from the prefab but thought of it as counter intuitive.

Thought of also adding a SpecificItem variable field in the data container template but that would require me to input all specific items  which doesn't seem right.

I wanted to avoid as much as possible using  strings/ or exact location path name for the SpecificItem. How would you go about this?

Comment: A type must inherit from `UnityEngine.Object` to be dragable "instance" in the inspector. I'm not sure I understand the relation between items and containers. What is the problem with an item being a field  in the container or to make items inherit from `ScriptableObject` and be dragable themselfs? Or both parts merged into one SO containing methods and data?